# How can I fix this error TypeError Network request failed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I run the login function says TypeError network request failed

```
login = () => {
  fetch('http://192.881.5.222:3000/user',{
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            "username": this.state.username,
            "password": this.state.password,
          })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
    
          alert(res.message);
    
          if(res.success === true){
            AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.user);
            this.props.NavigationContainer.Stack('Profile');
           
          } else {
            alert(res.message);
          }
        })
        .done();
    }
 }
```

I have updated my file.plist, I even change the listening port but nothing seems to work.

I'm using an iPhone. a real device using expo client

Comment: This is react native app, I have tried many attempts to solve this, I do understand that iPhones reject HTTP, so that's why I had to update my file.plist to accept HTTP:

Comment: Can you add a catch, and post the entire error

Comment: also try adding , android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml and check

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS thanks mate, it worked.

Comment: @ Ab happy to help, kindly please accept and vote if it helped you so it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as discussed on the comments the fix was adding a config in

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml
```